# create socket pool in python (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, tcp, python-multiprocessing

I created a tcp client class. (Sending auth_message is necessary)

```
class Connector:

    auth_prefix = b'~~~~~~~~'
    auth_success = b'~~~~~~~~~~~'
    eod = b'~~~~~~~~~'

    apikey = b'~~~~~~~~~~'

    socket_timeout = 5
    socket_buffer = 1000



    def __init__(self, address, project):
        import socket
        self.project = project
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.settimeout(self.socket_timeout)
        self.sock.connect(address)
        auth_message = self.auth_prefix + self.apikey + b',' + project.encode('utf-8')

        if self.auth_success in self.send_message(auth_message) :
            print(f'Successfully connected to {address}')
        else :
            print('connection failure')


...

    def send_message(self, message):
        if type(message) is not bytes :
            message = message.encode('utf-8')
        self.sock.sendall(message)
        self.sock.sendall(self.eod)
        record = b''
        while True :
            record += self.sock.recv(self.socket_buffer)
            if record.endswith(self.eod) :
                break
        return record
```

This class has no problem with single thread. But I want to try multiprocessing pool due to speed problem.

I want to make a tcp connector class only in the init and reuse it as a pool afterwards.

What should I do?

**(it's the same idea as create multiple database sessions and crud using multiple thread.)**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with  Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        res = [pool.apply_async(some_method, args=('XXXXXXX')) for line in range(1,1000)]
        return_message = [r.get() for r in res]
```

Comment: I am not a great fan of multi-threading *except* for network servers. In Python, we use multi-processing for heavy computional tasks because of the Global Interpreter Lock. What is the reason for using multi-processing instead of multi-threading here?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm  sending millions of messages to the server and using the return value. But the server is not programmed efficiently, it uses very low resources to send responses . To solve this problem, I would like to reduce my response time by sending multiple messages.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still cannot understand why 8 processes could be better than 16 threads or even better 64 sockets managed by select in one single thread.

Comment: @SergeBallesta What do you mean by 64 sockets and 16 threads? A single thread works on a single socket connection.I just want to make 8 connections and use 8 threads on the server. This socket server is designed to use multiple sessions.

Comment: `select` allows a single thread to process a number of sockets.